# How best to parse a comma separate list in PEG grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, left-recursion, pegjs

I'm trying to parse a comma separated list. To simplify, I'm just using digits. These expressions would be valid:

(1, 4, 3)

()

(4)

I can think of two ways to do this and I'm wondering why exactly the failed example does not work. I believe it is a correct BNF, but I can't get it to work as PEG. Can anyone explain why exactly? I'm trying to get a better understanding of the PEG parsing logic.

I'm testing using the online browser parser generator here:
https://pegjs.org/online

This does not work:

```
list = '(' some_digits? ')'
some_digits = digit / ', ' some_digits
digit = [0-9]
```

(actually, it parses okay, and likes () or (1) but doesn't recognize (1, 2)

But this does work:

```
list = '(' some_digits? ')'
some_digits = digit another_digit*
another_digit = ', ' digit
digit = [0-9]
```

Why is that? (Grammar novice here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cool question and after digging around in their docs for a second I found that the `/` character means:

> Try to match the first expression, if it does not succeed, try the
>   second one, etc. Return the match result of the first successfully
>   matched expression. If no expression matches, consider the match
>   failed.

So this lead me to the solution:

```
list = '(' some_digits? ')'
some_digits = digit ', ' some_digits / digit
digit = [0-9]
```

The reason this works:

input: (1, 4)

- eats '('
- check are there some digits?
- check some_digits - first condition:

  - eats '1'
  - eats ', '
  - check some_digits - first condition:

    - eats '4'
    - fails to eat ', '
  - check some_digits - second condition:

    - eats '4'
    - succeeds
  - succeeds
- eats ')'
- succeeds

if you reverse the order of the `some_digits` conditions the first number is comes across gets eaten by `digit` and no recursion occurs. Then it throws an error because ')' is not present.

Comment: On a side note for line two this works as well: `some_digits = digit (', ' some_digits)?`

Comment: @LeonStarr Oh, did you want me to answer the second part of your post? Sorry I forgot

Comment: No need James, your answer clarified the PEG parsing logic for me (which was my real problem). But thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

`some_digits = '(' digit (', ' digit)* ')'`

It depends on what you want with the values and on the PEG implementation, but extracting them might be easier this way.